# Import of csv gives a data frame with only one variable

Tags: r, csv, import

I am having some trouble correctly importing a csv-file into R. All the descriptions I find searching for csv-import says to just use an approach as following:

```
dataFrame <- read.csv2("file_Name.csv")
```

or

```
  dataFrame <- read.csv(file="file_Name.csv",
                    header=TRUE, sep=",")
```

However, both solutions gives a data frame with all data in one variable.

Here is how the excel file looks like:

[image]

Does anyone have input on correct import?

Comment: Welcomet to SO! It seems that your question is regarding R rather than regarding Excel. What are you looking for?

Comment: Paste couple of rows from your file as text. Try using `read.table` or `data.table::fread`

Comment: Perhaps the quotes that wrap your data are confusing the file formatting? I think in Excel, these are usually invisible, and so there may be extra quotes in your CSV output. Try removing them, and reading the file into Excel as comma delimted using Data -> From Text, and then save that as a csv before reading it into R.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: There was an issue when downloading the csv-file from the website, when I tried downloading it in an alternative way, it was correctly formatted and the standard import strategies worked.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your delimiter is a semicolon. You may specify the delimiter with the `delim` parameter.

Try running this:

```
dataFrame <- read_delim("file_Name.csv", delim = ";", escape_double = FALSE, trim_ws = TRUE)
```

Comment: Needs some editing

Comment: The diff is confusing. The change to the code is removing two newlines after "`delim = ";", `". Is there significant white space in R (except the obvious)?

Comment: @Marco: Can you elaborate?